# How can I get a VBA script to disregard a paragraph break at the end of a selection?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro in Word that adds smart quotes to selected text:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub addquotes() 
Dim r As Range 
With ActiveDocument 
     'check for extra spaces and punctuation &
     'select the entire word or phrase
    Set r = Selection.Words(Selection.Words.Count) 
    If r.Characters(r.Characters.Count) = " " Then 
        Set r = .Range(Selection.Words(1).Start, _ 
        Selection.Words(Selection.Words.Count).End - 1) 
    Else 
        Set r = .Range(Selection.Words(1).Start, r.End) 
    End If 
     'check to see if AutoformatasYouType is being used
    If Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes Then 
        r.InsertBefore Chr(147) 
        r.InsertAfter Chr(148) 
    Else 
        r.InsertBefore Chr(34) 
        r.InsertBefore Chr(34) 
    End If 
End With 
 '    select the results as reference...can be commented if not needed
r.Select 
End Sub
```

It generally works just as I need, but I have one glitch I don't know how to fix. When I select an entire paragraph in Word, the final smart quote gets placed in a new paragraph, rather than at the end of the selected paragraph. For instance:

> If only Uncle Monty knew what we know, Violet said, and Stephano knew that he knew what we know. But Uncle Monty doesn't know what we know, and Stephano knows that he doesn't know what we know.

becomes

> “If only Uncle Monty knew what we know,” Violet said, “and Stephano knew that he knew what we know. But Uncle Monty doesn't know what we know, and Stephano knows that he doesn't know what we know.
> ”

Is there a way to tweak the code to check for a line break or paragraph break at the end and adjust the selection to include only the actual text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check line break or paragraph mark with ASCII.

| Editing Mark | Shortcut Key | ASCII |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Line Break | Shift+Enter | 11 |
| Paragraph Mark | Enter | 13 |

```vb
Sub addquotes()
    Dim r As Selection, i, ascChr
    If Selection.End <> Selection.Start Then
        Set r = Selection
        For i = r.End To r.Start + 1 Step -1
            ascChr = Asc(ActiveDocument.Range(i - 1, i))
            If Not (ascChr = 11 Or ascChr = 13 Or ascChr = 32) Then
                r.End = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'check to see if AutoformatasYouType is being used
        If Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes Then
            r.InsertBefore Chr(147)
            r.InsertAfter Chr(148)
        Else
            r.InsertBefore Chr(34)
            r.InsertBefore Chr(34)
        End If
    End If
    '    select the results as reference...can be commented if not needed
    r.Select
End Sub
```